# How to view source code for functions of type "special"?

Tags: r, code-inspection

For 'normal' functions, simply typing

```
>  my_func
```

without parentheses will cause the function code to show up in the console. Functions of type "special" will not do so, e.g., at best,

```
get('for')
.Primitive("for")
```

Other than examining the core R source code, is there any call that will return the source for these functions?

Comment: The code for these functions is not written in R; it is compiled from C code, and only exists in your R installation as machine code. Your R installation does not keep a full copy of its own source code (why would it?). So the answer is "no, you need to look at the source code". I'm not sure what benefit there would be in perusing C code in the R console without the context such as includes, macros etc that would allow you to make sense of it. For completeness, the code is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/50184ddc484e0b1f368c272c486bce79afd73dfa/src/main/eval.c#L2736)

Comment: `pryr::show_c_source(.Primitive("for"))` prints in the console how it is called in C and takes you to a search of github. It's not the first result, but it's down there in eval.c I think. It searches for "do_for", so it also returns results for things like "do_format".

Comment: fyi that function is discussed briefly in the very long answer at the probably canonical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) so this should probably be a duplicate.

Comment: @joran I agree this is a dupe of that referenced answer.  Thanks.